# Counting number of session at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-intelligence

I'm using SQL server.
I'm doing a BI report and I would like to calculate **the total number of sessions that are connected at the same time per application and country**.

I have a table **DimDateTime** contains the ID of date and time.

```
DateTimeKey      DateTime                  Date         Month  MonthName  Year        Hour
202007010000    2020-07-01 00:00:00.000    2020-07-01    7    juillet    2020    00:00:00
202007010001    2020-07-01 00:01:00.000    2020-07-01    7    juillet    2020    00:01:00
202007010002    2020-07-01 00:02:00.000    2020-07-01    7    juillet    2020    00:02:00
202007010003    2020-07-01 00:03:00.000    2020-07-01    7    juillet    2020    00:03:00
202007010004    2020-07-01 00:04:00.000    2020-07-01    7    juillet    2020    00:04:00
202007010005    2020-07-01 00:05:00.000    2020-07-01    7    juillet    2020    00:05:00
202007010006    2020-07-01 00:06:00.000    2020-07-01    7    juillet    2020    00:06:00
.....
```

I have a table called **Application** and another one called **Country** that contains the Ids and information about the application and the country.

I have a table **TestSession** that contains this data:

```
SessionID |StartDate            | EndDate               | Application_ID | Id_Country 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 01/06/2020 23:50    |   01/07/2020 06:02    |   1            |  1
2         | 01/06/2020 23:45    |   01/07/2020 00:45    |   1            |  2
3         | 01/06/2020 23:30    |   01/07/2020 01:02    |   2            |  2
4         | 01/06/2020 23:10    |   01/07/2020 00:53    |   2            |  2
5         | 01/06/2020 23:56    |   01/07/2020 10:20    |   1            |  2
6         | 01/06/2020 23:49    |   01/07/2020 02:15    |   1            |  4
7         | 01/06/2020 22:45    |   01/06/2020 23:58    |   2            |  1
8         | 01/06/2020 23:34    |   01/07/2020 00:02    |   2            |  4
9         | 01/07/2020 00:00    |   01/07/2020 03:32    |   2            |  3
10        | 01/07/2020 00:02    |   01/07/2020 02:12    |   1            |  3
....
```

I would like to obtain the total number of connections  at a specific time (Minutes). For example:
application_ID
2020/07/01 00:01

```
Datekey    | Application_ID |   Id_Country | Total_Connections| 
----------------------------------------------------------
202007010001| 1            |   1         | 1
202007010001| 1            |   2         | 2
202007010001| 1            |   3         | 0
202007010001| 1            |   4         | 1
202007010001| 2            |   1         | 0
202007010001| 2            |   2         | 2
202007010001| 2            |   3         | 1
202007010001| 2            |   4         | 1
202007010002| 1            |   1         | 1
202007010003| 1            |   2         | 1

....
```

I built the query below and it works. However it takes to much time for processing.
Do you have another solution less complex and faster?
Thanks in advance

```sql
declare @HeureCurrent datetime;
declare @id_pays int; 
declare @id_application int;
declare @max_id_pays int;
declare @max_id_application int;
set @HeureCurrent = '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
set @id_pays = 0
set @id_application = 0
set @max_id_pays = (select MAX(id) from dbo.TestSession)
set @max_id_application =(select MAX(id_int) from dbo.TestSession)


While @HeureCurrent < '2020-07-01 00:01:00'
begin 
    while @id_pays <= @max_id_pays 
    begin
        while @id_application <= @max_id_application
        begin
            set @nombre_de_connection = (  select COUNT(sessionKey) from dbo.TestSession
                                           where StartDate < @HeureCurrent and EndDate > @HeureCurrent
                                           and [id_Application] = @id_application 
                                           and id_Country = @id_pays);
                                           
            insert into dbo.TotalConnections
            SELECT [DateTimeKey],@id_application as Application , @id_pays as IsoCounty
             ,@nombre_de_connection as Nbr_Connection
                  FROM [dbo].[DimDateTime]
                  where DateTime = @HeureCurrent;
             set @id_application = @id_application+1
          end
      set @id_application = 0
      set @id_pays = @id_pays+1
     end
 set @HeureCurrent = DATEADD(MI, 1, @HeureCurrent)
 set @id_pays = 0
end
```

Comment: *"However it takes to much time for processing. "* That's because you're using a `WHILE`. SQL is a set based language, and performs horribly with such iterative based solutions.

Comment: The common approach: assign +1 to login, -1 to logout and apply a *Cumulative Sum* over it.

Comment: What does the `datekey` have to do with a date/time value?

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the data so there is one row per date/time and then aggregate and use a cumulative sum:

```
select v.dte, t.Application_ID, t.Id_Country, sum(inc) as inc,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (partition by t.Application_ID, t.Id_Country order by dte) as concurrent_users
from TestSession s cross apply
     (values (s.startdate, 1), (s.enddate, -1)
     ) v(dte, inc)
group by v.dte, t.Application_ID, t.Id_Country
order by v.dte, t.Application_ID, t.Id_Country;
```

This has one row per date/time in your original data.  Your results have some sort of numeric key that is not explained.  Of course, this can be further aggregated by day or some other time period.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I still have the problem. I want to get the simultaneous users given one hour. e.g.: If I have a table of 10 users logged in on **2020/07/01** of which **3 users** have a **start time 17:00** and an **end time 17:30**. If I filter for users logged in **at 17:25** I would like to get the day and time with the total number of users logged in (3 users). 

I'm doing a BI report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use right outer join to get the desired result:

```
SELECT B.*, COALESCE(A.TOTAL, 0) AS TOTAL FROM
 (SELECT Application_ID, Id_Country,
 COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM table1 a WHERE StartDate < '2020-01-07 00:01:00'
 AND ENDDATE > '2020-01-07 00:01:00' GROUP BY Application_ID, Id_Country) A
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT DISTINCT Application_ID, Id_Country FROM table1) B
 ON (A.APPLICATION_ID = B.APPLICATION_ID AND A.Id_Country = B.Id_Country);
```